# É permitido realizar a operação módulo % com número double em java, e como alterar uma posição unica de uma string em java?

Tags: java

Minhas duvidas..

- É permitido realizar a operação módulo % com número de ponto flutuante em java, e por que? Porque em compiladores como c++ essa operação não é permitida.
- Como faço para acessar um elemento de uma string e altera-lo ? Exemplo, tenho uma string.
  String s = "ola";
  Como alterar a posição 0 do elemento por uma letra o maíscula ?
- É permitido, acessar uma String como um array ? exemplo str[i].

Comment: Acho que você deveria fazer três perguntas diferentes ao invés de colocar três coisas bem diferentes numa só.

Comment: https://ideone.com/xixih2

Comment: Cada pergunta deve ser esperada, com tempo de 40 minutos.

Comment: Você pode [edit] esta, deixar a dúvida que julgar mais importante e futuramente abrir as outras perguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:

```
class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(6.25 % 2.5);
    }
}
```

Saída: 1.25.

2: `String`s são imutáveis! Ou seja, você teria que criar uma nova `String` ao invés de alterar a já existente. Por exemplo:

```
String s = "ola";
String s2 = "x" + s.substring(1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

A saída é `xla`.

3: Não. Mas você pode fazer algo assim:

```
String s = "teste";
char[] array = s.toCharArray();
array[2] = 'x';
String s2 = new String(array);
```

Comment: Mas tipo, no caso é inviável utilizar Java e ficar alterando a string para char né ? é melhor montar outra..

Comment: @VictorOCV As strings em Java tem como uma de suas premissas o fato de não poderem nunca ser alteradas. Se isso fosse permitido, iria se tornar um caos. A abordagem é você sempre montar outra, e para isso você pode usar `char[]`, pode usar métodos da própria classe `String` que criam outras `String`s e pode usar as classes `StringBuilder` e `StringJoiner`.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.